# The action POP with payload was not handled by any navigator

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v5, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I have no idea what is causing this bug in my react native app. I'm using version 5 of the React Navigation library.

[image]

It **randomly** crashes the app **sometimes**. Google searching hasn't helped me understand what this is. It's **very selective** though which is a good(or a bad) thing.

So what does this mean and what could be causing it?

Comment: It can happen if you're trying to pop if there's no screens to go back to (e.g. click multiple times on the header back button). It's a development only error log. Not a crash. You can dismiss it and continue to use the app. The error won't be shown in production.

Comment: In my case, the error was occurring while more data was being fetched from an API. This was on the initial screen so there was no header back button. Although, I was scrolling down on a few occasions.

Comment: Your explanation makes sense but the example doesn't apply to me. Could you think of any other examples?

Comment: Hard to say without looking at your code

Comment: It might be a bug: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/6820

Comment: make sure, that if you call it from a function (like a callback) put `return` before :-)
Also next time, please also add a code sample causing this or all code samples that could be causing this if you don't know :-)

Answer (score 6):

```
if(navigation.canGoBack()) {
  navigation.dispatch(StackActions.pop(1));
}
```

see  https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/7814#issuecomment-599921016

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this?

```
this.props.navigation.goBack()
```

Comment: This is happening on the initial screen so I'm not executing such code.

Answer (score 1):

It means you tried to pop a view where there was nothing to pop. It might mean there's a bug in your app because, generally, you shouldn't be popping a view when there isn't any to pop.

But it can also be part of intentional design where you have insufficient knowledge of the current navigation state, but need to make sure at least one pop is done (similar to clearing a flag variable even if it might not be set in the first place, in which case it would be a no-op). If that's the case, then you can disable this development-level warning:

```
const temp = console.error;
console.error = () => {};
navigation.pop();
console.error = temp;
```

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted; this was perfect for my case! Thank you Aaron :)

Answer (score 1):

**Error Cause**: goBack() or pop() is getting called multiple times. Sometimes onPress event gets called many times. You can check by adding console.log().

**How to Solve**: you need to [throttle](https://lodash.com/docs/#throttle) the onPress function.

**Example**:

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
import { Text, View } from 'react-native'
import { throttle } from 'lodash'

export default class Test extends PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
    
        this.state = {
             
        }
        this.onPress = throttle(this.onPress, 500, {trailing: false})
    }
    

    onPress = () => {
        console.log("going back")
        this.props.navigation.pop();
        //this.props.navigation.goBack();
    }
     
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>Hello World!</Text>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to check there can go back or not by `canGoBack` method like this

```
import {  StackActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

if(this.refs.navigation.canGoBack())
{
  this.refs.navigation.dispatch(StackActions.pop(1));
// this.refs.navigation.dispatch(StackActions.popToTop());
}
```